# Run background services on battery saver mode Android

Tags: java, android, background-process

I have a service for sending http request that runs on background and works fine on "normal mode". The problem is when I put my phone on "battery saver mode", the service not working. But, apps like Whatsapp still working. Do you have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Most likely, they are not using a continuously-running service, but instead respond to GCM/FCM push messages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mobile applications like Whatsapp must be requesting permission to exempt them from Doze/battery saving and App standby mode.

It is possible to configure this manually by configuring the Whitelist in **Settings > Battery > Battery Optimization**.

Alternatively from API 23, you can use permissions model to request users to whitelist them (refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#support_for_other_use_cases)). From API You can also check whether your app is currently on White list by calling [isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(java.lang.String))

However you need to satisfy certain [criteria](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#whitelisting-cases) for being able to whitelist yourself. Otherwise you face issues while maintaining app on Google Play Store.

But mostly messenger apps like Whatsapp are triggered through high-priority push notifications so they are more likely to be active despite not running background process.

Comment: No whatsapp do not request for Battery Optimization. they reply on FCM high-priority message.

Comment: @NitZRobotKoder any solution so far ?

Comment: @Ahmad The solution is to rely on High priority FCM for getting notifications and then fetching data from your own service to show notifications or whatever else you want to do from the background. In newer Android versions, you do have around 7-8 seconds to complete your background tasks after receiving a notification.
Plus if it is possible, then try to get that ignore battery optimization request for your application as an extra safety measure.

Answer (score 9):

Add permission

```
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

request whitelist your app

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            String packageName = getPackageName();
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
            if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The background services are being worked on since Marshmallow and are not to be used for anything else than foreground usage since Oreo.

The doze mode will forbide any operation while active, the phone will get out of doze for few Ms every X hours, some library will allow you to make some operations during that time.

If you want to do some background operation during the doze & Battery saver you may want to have a look at the  [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) for operation that will be executed every 15 minutes or more while the phone is not in doze and if you require operations more often, i would advice you to have a look at the [JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android). Both will execute your task when going out of the doze mode

Answer (score 0):

Using workers will enable your application to run in the doze windows but network calls will be forbidden.
Therefore you need to request for ignore battery optimization so that you can make network calls.