# how to continuously Run Service in Bankground above Lollipop?

Tags: android, background-process

i have created one TimerTask and one Service.i want to check continuously current foreground App Name. But When My App get closed after 1 or 2 minute service is Not Active.How can i run my Service continuously.

In emulator it's working fine but in Real Device service stop after sometime

BackgroundService.java

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {



private Timer mTimer;


public BackgroundService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


}

private void startTimer() {
    if (mTimer == null) {
        mTimer = new Timer();
        AppLockTimerTask lockTask = new AppLockTimerTask(this);
        mTimer.schedule(lockTask, 0L, 1000L);
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    startTimer();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    mTimer.cancel();
    mTimer.purge();
    mTimer = null;
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent bootCompleteReceiver = new Intent("com.android.background");
    sendBroadcast(bootCompleteReceiver);
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {

    mTimer.cancel();
    mTimer.purge();
    mTimer = null;
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent bootCompleteReceiver = new Intent("com.android.background");
    sendBroadcast(bootCompleteReceiver);
}}
```

AppLockTimerTask.java

```
public class AppLockTimerTask extends TimerTask {

private static final String TAG = "AppLockTimerTask";
private MySharedPreferences mySharedPreferences;
private DBHelper dbHelper;
private Context mContext;


public AppLockTimerTask(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
    mySharedPreferences = MySharedPreferences.getInstance(mContext);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    printForegroundTask();
}

private void printForegroundTask() {

    String currentApp = "NULL";
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 1000, time);
        if (appList != null && appList.size() > 0) {
            SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
            for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
                mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
            }
            if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                currentApp = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
            }
        }
    } else {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        currentApp = tasks.get(0).processName;
    }

    Log.e(TAG, "Current App in foreground is: " + currentApp);
    getNewCurrentApp(currentApp);
}

private void getNewCurrentApp(String currentApp) {
    if (!currentApp.equals("com.dharmendra.applock_timerbase")) {
        String previousApp = mySharedPreferences.getData(Constant.previousOpenAppName);
        if (previousApp.equals("")) {
            mySharedPreferences.saveData(Constant.previousOpenAppName, currentApp);
        } else {
            if (previousApp.equals(currentApp)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "App Not Change ==>" + currentApp);

            } else {

                Log.d(TAG, "App Change ==>" + currentApp);
                HashMap<String, String> map = dbHelper.selectFromLI(currentApp);
                if (map.size() > 0) {
                    if (map.get("type").equals("p")) {
                        Intent i = new Intent();
                        i.setClassName("com.dharmendra.applock_timerbase", "com.dharmendra.applock_timerbase.OpenPatternLock");
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        i.putExtra("previousApp", previousApp);
                        i.putExtra("currentApp", currentApp);
                        i.putExtra("type", "p");
                        mContext.startActivity(i);
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Timmer Lock");
                    }
                } else {
                    mySharedPreferences.saveData(Constant.previousOpenAppName, currentApp);
                }


            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run background services on battery saver mode Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639229/run-background-services-on-battery-saver-mode-android)

Comment: You can use the WorkManager API, which works from API level 14 and above.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a long background service above Android 5.0 to Android 7 by using:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

On Android 8  onwards you must use Firebse JobDispatcher, GCMNetworkmanager etc.

Comment: return START_STICKY is not working for me. i have try in Android 7.1

Comment: Then try with JobDisptcher . There are some background execution limitation for Android Version > 7.0